# Android list adapter with an array list in each list item

Tags: android, json, listview, listadapter

I want to create a custom list adapter which is being populated by a json array using volley but i want to put a list of items in each list item which are clickable. below is an example json which i want to use to populate the list

```
[
{
    "name": "Hopewell Mutanda",
    "answer": "This is my answer",
    "votes": 10,
    "date": 20-06-2014,
    "comments": [
                 {
                    "comment": "This is a great answer",
                    "name": "Gloria Nyakudya",
                    "date": 21-10-2014,
                    "vote": 20,
                 },
                ]
},
```

]

Below is what i expect in the end but i did the layout manually. i want to do it using an adapter. Please not that the comments list have their own xml resource with two different textviews too. the comments should be clickable.

http://encodable.com/uploaddemo/files/Screenshot_2014-12-02-23-55-33.png

My question is how do i go about modifying my custom adapter to suit these requrements. i am going to use an adapter similar to this one just going to make a few name changes.

```
private  class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private LayoutInflater mInflater;

   public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
       mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   }

   public int getCount() {
       return mDataList.size();
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder holder;

       if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list_item, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();

        mFeedImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_image);
            mFeedImageAuthor = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_image_image_author);
            mFeedTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_title);
            mFeedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_date);
            mFeedAuthor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_author);
            mFeedTag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_tag);

           convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoSlab-Light.ttf");
       mFeedTitle.setTypeface(custom_font);
       holder.mFeedTitle.setText(mDataList.get(position).getsFeedTitle());
       holder.mFeedDate.setText(mDataList.get(position).getsFeedDate()) ;
       holder.mFeedAuthor.setText(mDataList.get(position).getsFeedAuthor()) ;
       holder.mFeedTag.setText(mDataList.get(position).getsFeedTag()) ;


       mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  }
                        });

       return convertView;

            }
   class ViewHolder {
       TextView mFeedTitle, mFeedDate, mFeedAuthor, mFeedTag;
       ImageView mFeedImage, mFeedImageAuthor;

   }    

}
```

Comment: `but i want to put a list of items in each list item which are clickable` - can you explain how you visualize your list precicely

Comment: I'm confused too. Is mListView the list that this adapter is providing views for? Or are you wanting to put a ListView inside one of your list items (and into your holder). A list-in-a-list seems like a bad idea. Are you sure you need that? Could you instead give a count of how many comments the item has, and then have a separate details view for when they click on an item?

Comment: Guys please check my edit and click the link. i thonk it may help explain what i want to achieve

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that it's possible for a single listview item to have multiple clickable areas.  Lists like this could be done similar to how sectioned lists work.

You could try something like [this](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

[image]

A more complicated version of this should accomplish what you're trying to do, unless I've misunderstood your intent, but with this you should be able to define 2 or 3 or more different row layouts and order them however you wish.

Comment: It may not be possible to have nested listviews but it may be possible to have a linearlayout which is populated using an addview. If you take a look at the android stackachange app